# How to prevent "‘amplify-authenticator’ is not a known element" error in unit tests when using Amplify UI Components

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, aws-amplify

I am using the [Amplify UI Components](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/q/framework/angular) for [Angular](https://angular.io) V 10. When unit-testing my application, I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: ‘amplify-authenticator’ is not a known element
```

In order to prevent this error, I'm importing the AmplifyUIAngularModule in the testing configuration of the component:

```
import { AmplifyUIAngularModule } from '@aws-amplify/ui-angular';

beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AmplifyUIAngularModule
      ]
    })
})
```

This resolves the first error, but triggers another one:

```
Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly.
The configuration object is missing required auth properties.
Did you run amplify push after adding auth via amplify add auth?
See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup for more information
```

So obviously it’s telling me that the AmplifyUIAngularModule can’t be initialized without a config. I tried to add it, although it feels wrong, as the component should not connect in a unit test, but be mocked:

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
      ....
    },
  });
```

This indeed resolves the error, but when karma/jasmine tries to connect to headless chrome for testing, there is a timeout. I suspect the [amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/) stuff is trying to connect indeed, which can’t be the way to go in a unit test.

There are various threads on SO about how to mock a AWS/Amplify call, but I can't find anything about how to prevent the missing amplify-authenticator dependency.

Comment: If you don't need any of the functionality, you can just mock the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [Mike S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13258211/mike-s) correctly pointed out, mocking the whole component works just fine:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'amplify-authenticator',
  template: '',
})
class AmplifyAuthenticatorMock {}

beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AmplifyAuthenticatorMock,
        AppComponent,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });
```